# how using prisma where not & or condition Questions +(_count more one same table)

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

the (NOT invoice_number: null | invoice_number: "") condition doesn't work.
help please :(

**Sorry for my lack of English skills.**

```
const result = await prisma.order.findMany({
  where: {
    shipment: {
      some: {
        NOT: {
          OR: [
            {
              invoice_number: null,
            },
            {
              invoice_number: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

order : shipment = 1 : many relation.

model order {
id                         Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
.
.
.
shipment                   shipment[]
}

model shipment {
id                  Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
.
.
.
order               order?    @relation(fields: [order_id], references: [id])
}

- How can I use more than one counter in the same table?

(ex)

```
select: {
  _count: {
    select: { order: true },
    select: { order: { where: { order_price: { gt: 10 } } } },  // this code error
   }
}
```

```
const result = await prisma.order.findMany({
  where: {
    shipment: {
      some: {
        NOT: {
          invoice_number: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

this code doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide a sample repository with reproduction of this, so that I can run this locally and check?